Why gap between arrow-head and smooth line
How to prevent this gap between the line and the arrow-head?

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,arrows.meta,bending}    

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \draw[thick,fill=black!20,anchor=south west] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);

    \node   (x0)    at (-1.4cm, -1.0cm){};
    \node   (x1)    at (0.0cm, 0.3cm){};
    \node   (x2)    at (2.5cm, -0.8cm){};
    \node   (x3)    at (1.7cm, 1.3cm){};
    \node   (x4)    at (-0.7cm, 1.1cm){};

    \draw[-Latex,thick,black] plot [smooth] coordinates {(x0) (x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};
    \node[anchor=north]      (x0_font)   at (x0)     {$x_0$};
    \node[anchor=south]      (x1_font)   at (x1)     {$x(t)$};
    \node[]                  (set_label) at (0,-1.2) {$\mathcal{C}$};
    \node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]   at (x0)     {};
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \caption{A trajectory $\boldsymbol{x}(t)$ withi the safe set $\mathcal{C}$.}
  \label{fig:safeSetC}
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Quickfix: -{Latex[quick]}. If you use -{Latex[bend]} you see a very long transformed arrow tip. This is about the length the line is shortened with arrow tip option flex (the default if you load bending library). Seems to be related to bug #1079. See also Q624557, the proposed solution won't work with a plot, though.

The plothandler smooth places the last control point on the point x4, I believe. An alternative solution is to use the hobby library with the hobby key, i.e. plot[hobby] coordinates {…}. This results in a very different but curvier curve.

Problem is your use of the bending library. If in your example you remove it from preamble, you will get what you after.
Edit:
Problem is wrong use of bending library. If instead of
\draw[-Latex,thick,black] plot [smooth] coordinates {(x0) (x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};

you would use
\draw[-{[bend]Latex},thick,black] plot [smooth] coordinates {(x0) (x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};

as meanwhile suggest @Qrrbrbirlbel in his comment, than your problem will disappear
Some off-topic suggestion: you can draw your image on the following shorter way:
\documentclass[margin=3mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,fill=black!20,anchor=south west] (0,0) ellipse (3cm and 2cm);
    \coordinate[label=below:$x_0$]  (x0)    at (-1.4cm, -1.0cm){};
    \coordinate[label=$x(t)$]       (x1)    at (0.0cm, 0.3cm){};
    \coordinate   (x2)    at (2.5cm, -0.8cm){};
    \coordinate   (x3)    at (1.7cm, 1.3cm){};
    \coordinate   (x4)    at (-0.7cm, 1.1cm){};

\draw[-{[bend]Latex[length=1.2mm,width=2mm]}, thick, black] plot [smooth] coordinates {(x0) (x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};
    \node[]                  (set_label) at (0,-1.2) {$\mathcal{C}$};

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Of course, above code also work if you insert it in figure environment and use article ` document class.


That's not a good solution if OP wants to use bended arrow tips otherwise. It would be better to use quick (see my comment) to disable the bending/turning of arrow tips locally to at least get a proper path.

@Qrrbrbirlbel, I realize this and prepare what is now in edited answer. However, you beat me for few minutes. I'm very slow typing of texts :-(

Thanks for both your solution to the problem and the hint for the shortened code, that's very helpful! I used the bending-library because of this post. Your solution works great now. Thanks also to @Qrrbrbirlbel for the contribution regarding bending.

The smooth plothandler \pgfplotshandlercurveto places the very first control point of the Bézier curve on the very first point (here x0) and the very last control point on x4. This seems to mess up the calculation that is activated by the bending library.
I believe this to be related to Q624557 and bug #1079.
For this specific curve, you could disable the process of the bending library (which sets flex for all arrow tips) by using quick again (which is the only and the default option when the bending library is not loaded).
This does not alter the path visibly and might be the easiest solution here.

Alternatively, the curve created by the hobby library, while very different, does not have this problem since it apparently creates proper control points even for the start and the end.

There's also the option to create the dot at the start of the curve with an arrow tip that is adjusted slighly (and the same problem occurs there as well).
Code
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending, quotes}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick, fill=black!20] (0,0) ellipse[x radius=3, y radius=2];
\coordinate["$x_0$" below]  (x0) at (-1.4, -1  )
 coordinate["$x(t)$" above] (x1) at ( 0  ,  0.3)
 coordinate                 (x2) at ( 2.5, -0.8)
 coordinate                 (x3) at ( 1.7,  1.3)
 coordinate                 (x4) at (-0.7,  1.1);

\draw[-{Latex[quick]}, thick] plot [smooth] coordinates {(x0) (x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};
\draw[- Latex,         gray ] plot [hobby ] coordinates {(x0) (x1) (x2) (x3) (x4)};

\node[]                  (set_label) at (0,-1.2) {$\mathcal{C}$};
\node[circle,fill,inner sep=1.5pt]   at (x0)     {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Output


Thank you very much for your explanation of the interaction between bending and smooth. I also find the tip about the modified Arrow-Head helpful.
